# infinite loop with angularjs httpInterceptor injecting service using toastr

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, angular-http-interceptors, toastr

I'm getting and issue with my httpInterceptor and my toastr Service. It always make infinite loop

- AlertService (using toastr)

```js
class AlertService {

    constructor(toastr) {
        this.toastr = toastr;
        this.toastrCommonOpts = {
            positionClass: "toast-bottom-center",
            allowHtml: true,
            closeButton: true,
        }
    }

    notificationError (msg, title) {
        let errorMsg = msg || 'error';
        this.toastr.error(errorMsg, title || '', this.toastrCommonOpts);
    };

    notificationWarning(msg, title) {
        let warningMsg = msg || 'warning';
        this.toastr.warning(warningMsg, title || '', this.toastrCommonOpts);
    }

    notificationSuccess(msg, title, duration) {
        let successMsg = msg || 'Success';
        this.toastr.success(successMsg, title || '', this.toastrCommonOpts);
    }

}
AlertService.$inject = ['toastr'];
export default AlertService ;
```

- myHttpInterceptor

```js
class HttpInterceptor {
    constructor() {
        ['request', 'response']
            .forEach((method) => {
                if(this[method]) {
                    this[method] = this[method].bind(this);
                }
            });
    }
}
class MyHttpInterceptor extends HttpInterceptor{

    constructor(AlertService) {
        super();
        this.AlertService = AlertService;
    }

    request(config) {
        this.AlertService.notificationSuccess();
        return config;
    };


    response(response){
        this.AlertService.notificationSuccess();
        return response;
    }
}

MyHttpInterceptor.$inject = ['AlertService'];
export default MyHttpInterceptor;
```

- myModule

```js
import MyHttpInterceptor from './myHttpInterceptor';
import AlertService from "./alert.service";

export default angular.module('app.core', [toastr])
    .service('AlertService', AlertService)
    .factory('MyHttpInterceptor', MyHttpInterceptor)
    .config(($httpProvider) => {
        $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('MyHttpInterceptor');
    });
```

I extends myHttpInterceptor and bind my methods to prevent loosing context 'this' (cf : [angularjs http interceptor class (ES6) loses binding to 'this'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28638600/angularjs-http-interceptor-class-es6-loses-binding-to-this) ). I did not succeed to use arrowFunctions as class methods.

I also tried to do it following [this issue](https://github.com/Foxandxss/angular-toastr/issues/160)

Would any of you have already encountered this problem?

Thanks :)

Comment: have you tried to use $injector.get('toastr'); in your alert service constructor?

Comment: `.factory('MyHttpInterceptor', MyHttpInterceptor)`. That's one problem at least. Classes should be used with `service` only. You likely had problems with arrows because of that, and you likely don't need neither arrows nor `bind` this way.

Comment: @ShreyanceJain Yes , already tried , i had the same issue.

Comment: @estus I also explore this. But i could not either define methods as arrow functions.

Comment: Likely because you used wrong service type, so arrows were bound to wrong context.